# Enlist Entity Framework into a SQLTransaction?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

We have a lot of legacy code that uses our own data object. We are slowly trying to introduce EF. We need the ability to enlist EF into a transaction we already started using System.Data.SqlClient.SQLTransaction. EF of course uses System.Transaction.Transaction. Is this possible?

To make things more clear. We have code all over the place that does the following:

```
public sub DeleteEntity()
     Dim InTransaction = ado.InTransaction
     if not InTransaction then ado.BeginTran
     ...
       <--want to use EF Here
     ...
     if not InTransaction then ado.CommitTran
end sub
```

The DeleteEntity routine is not simple. It has a lot of logic. I want to use EF for just want thing in the middle of the code so i need to enlist it in the active transaction. I can't just use transaction scope because of how it is designed. DeleteEntity is called in lots of places and i don't want to visit every place that calls the routine. It more has to deal with System.Transaction.Transaction and SqlTransaction then it does EF itself.

Update: I tried:

```
context.connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)
```

That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I  may be wrong but have you considered using ObjectQuery instead of using to Linq to Entities for the Delete operation. Here is what I found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx)

> Promotion of a transaction to a DTC may occur when a connection is
>   closed and reopened within a single transaction. Because the Entity
>   Framework opens and closes the connection automatically, you should
>   consider manually opening and closing the connection to avoid
>   transaction promotion. For more information, see How to: [Manually Open
>   the Connection from the Object Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738698.aspx).

Comment: ObjectQuery doesn't help. DeleteEntity is only an example. There are other functions where we want to use EF for one small piece. In this example. Delete Entity is 400 lines of code. I just not a simple delete of an entity from the database.